# Getting android cell phone number using command line

Tags: android, automation, adb, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I would like to get the cell phone number of any android device using the command line.

I have tried using:

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 4
```

and

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 5/6/7/8
```

and it returns `Permission denied`.

I was wondering if anyone has another solution?

Ps: phones are android 4.1 and above

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to obtain root access by using :

```
adb root
```

Then you'll find those command work. Usually the phone number will be returned by :

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 5
```

or by :

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 6
```

It depends on the device is single or dual sim. You'll need to do some string parsing work if you need this result to be recognized by machine.

Comment: `adb root` gives "adbd cannot run as root in production builds"